# Why was this (deleted) question closed as Too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

This question is very specific, and there are concrete, specific answers. I don't understand how it could be interpreted as too broad.

*[What type of random number generator is used in the gaming industry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426821/what-type-of-random-number-generator-is-used-in-the-gaming-industry)*

Slot machines and video poker machine use very specific methods for generating random numbers. Eleven people found the information useful enough to mark it as a favorite.

I will concede that many of the answers are terrible and don't directly address the question. But that doesn't make the question too broad.

**Furthermore**:  I don't see why the question should be closed (and deleted!) for any reason, as it complies with all the current question guidelines for StackOverflow:

- **Too Broad**:  Nope.  As we've hashed out in the comments, this is a well-scoped question that can be objectively answered.
- **Off Topic**:  Nope.  It's about software design of a random-number generator to meet certain constraints.
- **Primarily Opinion-Based**:  Nope.  The question can be objectively answered.
- **Duplicate**:  Nope.  (Which is particularly troublesome, as we're deleting the *only* version of this question.)

Are some of the answers bad?  Yes.  Many of them are off-topic and unsupported.  But that's not a reason to delete a question.  It's a reason to downvote the bad answers.

It seems to me we've put too many incentives and getting people to close lots of questions.  As a result, people feel compelled to race through queues of close votes, and some are making decisions on topics they aren't familiar with based on little more than the title of the question.  I'm concerned that we're deleting useful content from StackOverflow, which is directly counter to its goal.

Comment: note that number of favorites isn't always a good measure of how many people found it useful. I often favorite low quality posts that i vote for closure so i can come back to them later to re-evaluate that vote in the case the question is updated.

Comment: It's true that there are no perfect metrics.  https://xkcd.com/552/

Comment: Here's the source of closure: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=28800048#28800048 (though the message in the cv request in chat doesn't make much sense or match what it was actually closed as, so clearly there was a little disagreement.)

Comment: I'm struggling to see this as a programming question. If the question is, "How do gambling machines generate secure random numbers?" I think such a question would be suited for http://security.stackexchange.com. Alternately if it's requesting an algorithm or hardware recommendation, that's off-topic for SO, but there are some beta SE sites where it *might* be on-topic, if maybe not the best place to ask.

Comment: @KevinB I already pinged our members that were involved [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29432829#29432829). I assume they are happy to explain their reasoning. It qualified for the old question got new answer attention.

Comment: I agree with the closure, i just wanted to bring up the history so maybe it can be clarified.

Comment: well you are metaeffecting it to get back opened, so I hope you cast a vote to reclose it when it does get reopened.

Comment: It might still be too broad, but I added "casino" to the title to narrow the focus a bit. At least now it's not wide open.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara:  I'd be less concerned if it were closed as not a programming question.  However, we have an awful lot of software design questions on the site, so that wouldn't be a slam dunk in my mind.

Comment: Not a duplicate because:  It's not obvious that this was closed for the wrong reason because it's not obvious that it should have been closed at all.  It's a perfectly valid question by the current guidelines, even if some of the answers are not.

Comment: I suggested it *might* be a duplicate, and based on the comments, it seemed you agreed it might be off-topic, the close reason I'm actually in favor of as it seems to be a software/hardware recommendation question or a request for off-site resource such as regulations that must be followed. I'm also not sure software-design questions are on-topic here, as "How do I design this?" is primarily-opinion-based. Such a questions might be better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this Meta question.  But that seems to happen whenever I try to better understand the rules for closing questions.  The criteria for closing SO questions seems to get more and more vague.

Answer (score 14):

I'm one of the close voters.

*As I recall*, I voted to close this question as "Primarily Opinion Based".

Maybe the system merged the reasons to "Too broad" because I was the only one to vote differently?

Anyway, my thought was: an answer would require some authority to decide what's "typically used" - such an answer would be opinion based and wouldn't fit Stack Oveflow's current guidelines.

So although it's indeed an interesting *topic* for a programmer, it's just not a *question for Stack Overflow*.

I hope my explanation helped you understand my vote.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I disagree with the assessment that it is primarily opinion based.  Some of the upvoted answers are off-topic and opinionated, but the _question_ is objectively answerable.

Answer (score 10):

The title is:

> What Type of Random Number Generator is Used in the Gaming Industry?

If you think about it, there are many different types of generators used for many different types of purposes, and there are many scenarios one could come up with in which one generator could be used over another.

It's *automatically* too broad.  Kind of a shame that so many people missed that.

It's also a hold-over from 2009, back when the site's requirements were less stringent.  I don't see much value in bringing it back today since it's still going to describe a very vast subject, given that gaming machines may use different types of algorithms for different purposes.

Comment: The (very short) question body asks specifically about poker machines and slot machines, which are regulated in how they can generate random numbers.  There are relatively few major manufacturers of the games, and they all use similar techniques to comply with the regulations.

Comment: 15 manufacturers is not legion.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Slot_machine_manufacturers  (which lists 17, but there are duplicates for Bally and WMS).

Comment: You can't judge broadness by title alone.  (Nor duplicates, but that's another battle.)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy:  Would "What type of random number generator is used in slot machines?" have been a better title, then?  Why would that have been more on-topic?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I doubt that either the close-voters nor anyone else (prior to closing) made the effort to research how many manufacturers of specific purpose-bound slot machines there are and to which regulations those are bound to. The question doesn't mention that and is thus, too broad.

Comment: well it will probably get reopened just to get reclosed a few times of the next few days

Comment: @Makoto:  Because specifying slot machines narrows the scope of the question dramatically.  You seemed to be complaining that the question is too broad because the gaming industry encompasses many things, which it does: slot machines, online poker, fantasy sports, etc.  But the question body selected a well-defined subset, thus making it quite specific.

Comment: @Linus Kleen:  I don't think the number of manufacturers is very relevant, but Makoto's response that it is "legion" is factually incorrect.  I don't understand why you conclude that the question is too broad because the question didn't mention the number of manufacturers.  The scope of "Why do cars have seatbelts?" doesn't really depend on the size of the automotive industry.  The fact is the regulations around the world are similar enough that virtual every manufacturer includes them.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy From what I read, the regulations does not specify the actual implementation, only criteria the implementation must fulfill. So long as the criteria are fulfilled, the how is for the manufacturer to decide.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy:  I'll concede that my response may have been a bit much.  I'll augment it.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara:  The regulations specify that they must generate random numbers at a certain rate, regardless of play, which nullifies the seeding question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy It's correct in the *scope* of your question, which didn't include the restraints that you were aware of while asking the question. If that were part of the question, the outcome might still have been the same, since - technically - it ain't programming related, but you'd have a better case. Also, *why* is entirely different from *which*, so the analogy of the automotive industry doesn't compare.

Comment: @LinusKleen:  To be clear, this is not my question.  I didn't ask it.  But it is one that I've referred other people back to many times over the years.  I'm not bringing it up here on meta to get it reopened.  I'm trying to understand how it was construed as too broad by anyone, let alone 10 people.  Too broad says that there are too many possible answers (not true here) or that a proper answer would be too long (again, not true here).

Comment: If it had been closed as not programming related, I could perhaps understand.  But too broad doesn't make sense here.

Comment: "If you think about it, there are many different types of generators used for many different types of purposes"  But there isn't much variety used in slot machines.  And I _have_ thought about it.  Please don't imply that I didn't.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy `s/your/OPs/g ; s/you/OP/g;` I apologize for that. The original argument remains, though: there were restraints that weren't disclosed as they (maybe) should have been. Hence the closure.

Comment: @Linus Kleen:  Sorry, I don't understand what you're saying.  What restraints weren't disclosed?  Do you mean the fact that the question was about slot machines?  That was part of the question since the original post.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy No. But the fact that there is a small amount of manufacturers all bound to a *specific* subset of PRNGs. All of which would have provided details to the question to *narrow it down*. You know, stuff you cited earlier.

Comment: what distinction are you trying to make with "automatically too broad" as opposed to just "too broad"?

Comment: @LinusKleen:  I still don't see what you're getting at.  You seem to be asking for the answer to the question to have been part of the question itself.